# GitHub Managing Multiple Repository

Tags: github, repository, multiple-repositories

I am managing a project and the scenario is that I need to first check the code written by my team and then after correcting it I need to push the code on the client repository.

So I think there should be two repository one is for us and another one is client repository which will have the final clean code.

Now when I am pushing the code on client repository It is showing all commits what we have on our repository that I do not want.

How can in one project folder manage both the repository individually ?

Comment: `So there is two repository one is local and another one is client repository.` ... so is the other repo also local, or is it the remote counterpart of the local repository?

Comment: I would go for branching. You do changes in one branch and merge it to the master, when it is reviewed. GitHub even has a function for selecting someone to review the code...

Comment: no @creyD I wants to know in terms of repository instead of having multiple branches.

Comment: @AnandShrivastava I see, but the logical approach for your problem would be to use branches. If you merge from one repo into the other it will still show you all of your commits, that´s what a versioning system does. If you want to get rid of the history (and therefore the commits) of a document you would need to develop outside of git and then add them to the final repository....